# Hydrostatic Condition in Fluid

Tags: fluid-statics

If we provide constant velocity to the partially filled container then the liquid present in the container is in the hydrostatic condition or not.

I think since velocity is constant then there is no acceleration so pressure will same at same height . Then it may be in hydrostatic condition.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If we provide constant velocity to the partially filled container then the liquid present in the container is in the hydrostatic condition or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the frame of the container is inertial, you don't have to change anything about the hydrostatic condition.
It would be different is the container was accelerating.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit blurry, but a change of velocity is governed by the Navier Stockes equation: either there is a gradient of pressure or a constraint applied. Therefore you cannot apply the hydrostatic hypothesis and a priori the pressure in the inlet and the outlet are different.